# How to maintain reference to update a nested array/dictionary (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on creating a comment thread that will add the comment to the appropriate nested spot. Here's an example comment thread (one main comment, with 3 direct replies [from Bob, James, Allan], 2 of those direct replies have their own direct replies [from John, Levy]):

```
[{
      username: "Kevin",
      date: "3 hours ago",
      text: "#Hello\n>quote\n\n",
      votes: 12,
      comments: [
        {
          username: "Bob",
          date: "2 hours ago",
          text: "^ click the minimize button to hide threads",
          votes: 8,
          comments: [
            {
              username: "John",
              date: "1 hours ago",
              text: "<- Click the arrows to vote",
              votes: 3,
              comments: [],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          username: "James",
          date: "4 hours ago",
          text: "click on reply to open up a text prompt",
          votes: 5,
          comments: [],
        },
        {
          username: "Allan",
          date: "10 mins ago",
          text: "this",
          votes: 2,
          comments: [
            {
              username: "Levy",
              date: "8 mins ago",
              text: "is",
              votes: 1,
              comments: [],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
]
```

I'm working in a component where this dictionary is passed through as a prop (prop.comments), and so is the setComments (react useState) function that can update this dictionary. I also have access to the **path** that the specific comment. I want to be able to add a comment to the comment whose path I have. For instance, a path could look like [0, 1]. This would mean go to the comment at index 0 (Kevin's), then the comment at index 1 ("James"). I would then add to James's comments.

The issue is that I don't know how to update a specific nested comment and then use setComment (the useState function) to actually update the original database. Here's what I've attempted, but it fails to update the original array.

props.comments: the entire array (as shown above)

props.setComments: the way to update this original array

props.path: the path to the specific comment (i.e. [0,1])

```
onClick={() => {
  let temp = [...props.comments];
  let originalData = [...temp];
  props.path.map((index, i) => {
    if (originalData) {
      originalData = [...originalData[index].comments];
    }
    if (i == props.path.length - 1) {
      let newArray = [...originalData];

      newArray.push({
        username: "Kevin",
        date: "now",
        text: "JASDFASDF",
        votes: 0,
        comments: [],
      });

      originalData = newArray;
    }
  });
  props.setComments(temp);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I would change how the comments array works. Currently, your comment objects look like this:

```
interface Comment {
  username: string;
  date: Date;
  text: string;
  votes: number;
  comments: Comment[];
}
```

The current problem you have is the nested comments.
To Not have this problem you can change the comment object to look like this:

```
interface Comment {
  id: string;
  replyTo: string | null;
  username: string;
  date: Date;
  text: string;
  votes: number;
}
```

Here, we've removed the comments array and replaced it with an `id`, for the current comment, and a `replyTo`, which would be the `id` of the comment this comment replied to. If it didn't reply to anything, then it would be null.

Now we won't have nesting, so you can easily loop through and add the comments. Also, the array should be easier to work with.